# What glue should be used to repair a delaminating fiberglass exterior door?

Tags: repair, doors, exterior, adhesive

The outer skin is starting to pull away from the core near the corners.  I think the skin is fiberglass.  It is a nice Pella door.  What would be the best glue/epoxy to repair this with?

[image]

Comment: My personal favorite way to fix that is to use polyester adhesive caulk.  You need to clamp the pieces together for a day, so that may be a deterrent to this procedure.  However the poly caulk stays pliable and is waterproof, so the elements that an exterior door encounter are not an issue, nor is slight movement of the frame.

Comment: I thought Pella had some pretty strong, if not limited lifetime guarantees? What did they say about this?

Comment: @handyman I'm not the original owner of the home/door.

Comment: Still worth contacting Pella. Even if not warrantied, they'll tell you how to repair it.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to advise with an actual product as it will be location specific. But, you'll need to look for a (MS) polymer based adhesive. These are a general construction adhesive, sealer and gap filler and will adhere to a wide range of materials.

Tec7 is the brand local to me, but you'll find one from all the big 'tube' type silicones/glues/etc. manufacturers.

Comment: What is the "(MS)" prior to the "polymer based adhesive"?

Comment: @FreeMan Modified Silicone